# Generation of compact Lagrangians over fields with characteristic 2

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Let $\pi:X\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a Lefschetz fibration, and assume that the fibers are exact or monotone. A classical result of Seidel says that all the closed weakly unobstructed Lagrangian submanifolds of $X$ are generated by Lefschetz thimbles of $\pi$ in the Fukaya category $\mathscr{F}(\pi)$ associated to the Lefschetz fibration $\pi$.

However, the above generation result is only true when the coefficient field $\mathbb{K}$ over which the Fukaya category $\mathscr{F}(\pi)$ is defined satisfies $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{K})\neq2$. This is because Seidel's proof involves a branched double covering trick.

To work over a field with $\mathrm{char}(\mathbb{K})=2$ one needs to pass to the wrapped Fukaya category $\mathscr{W}(X)$ and use the Viterbo restriction functor to obtain the generation by thimbles of unobstructed closed Lagrangians.

**My question** is that is it possible to obtain the generation of closed Lagrangians by thimbles over characteristic 2 without passing to the wrapped Fukaya category? This means one considers only ordinary Floer cohomology groups between closed Lagrangians and thimbles, rather than wrapped Floer cohomologies, or only compactly supported Hamiltonian perturbation and perturbations among thimbles are allowed, rather than perturbing using quadratic Hamiltonians.

Comment: I guess what you mean is that it is known that you can generate closed Lagrangians by thimbles in $W(X)$ (Abouzaid-Smith). Is the corresponding statement known in $F(\pi)$? I don't think a proof can be easily derived from facts in the literature. There is a) work in progress on a generation criterion for $F(\pi)$ (like what Abouzaid has done for the wrapped category) and b) I believe it is expected among experts that this will be applicable to the thimbles irrespective of the characteristic. I'm not sure how much of b) has been carried out.

Comment: @DanielPomerleano Yes. At least this is true for certain examples, say you can always generate matching spheres in $A_n$ surfaces by thimbles, as they are mapping cones of a non-trivial morphism between thimbles. However, this is true only when you know explicitly about the morphisms bewteen the closed Lagrangians and thimbles, in general it seems hard to figure out a proof without assuming the characteristic is not divisible by 2.